# Prolog Backtracking

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I am trying to do a word calculator .. read words from a file .. translate them into numbers and then calculate the result .. i managed to do all of that but i think i have two bugs in my program ..

I mainly have two functions ...

extract(Words),
 calculate( Words,0).

extract will read from the file .. and then return a list of Words .. ex: [one,plus,three] ..
now calculate will translate the value for these words into numbers and calculate ..
i managed to do that also .. 
now the bugs are : i must stop reading and terminate if i encounter stop in the file .. 
so if Words was [stop] End. 
i tried the following ...

```
execute :-
 extract(Words),
 Words = [stop],nl,print('Terminating ...'),!.
execute :-
 extract(Words),
 calculate( Words,0).
```

it successfully terminates .. but it skips lines as i extract more than once .. 
i have tried to do ..

```
execute :-
 extract(Words),
 Words \= [stop],execute(Words).
execute(Words) :-
 calculate( Words,0).
```

if the Words is not stop .. then go and calculate .. but its not working !!

i appreciate the help ..
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side-effects (here: reading from a file and moving on to the next term) are not undone on backtracking. You can read once and then make the choice based on the read term with if/then/else or an auxiliary predicate, for example:

```
execute :-
        extract(Words),
        (   Words == [stop] -> nl, write('Terminating ...')
        ;   calculate(Words, 0)
        ).
```

In SWI-Prolog, consider using [`library(pio)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pio) for pure file reading described via [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg), which handles backtracking as expected.

Comment: Thank you for the response .. i have tried to do that .. it is catching the stop .. printing .. but it keeps reading .. i want it to stop parsing the file and thats it .. i cant just say seen, told, after that to stop reading .. thanks a lot .. i appreciate your help

Comment: s(X) for the reference to `pio`.